# Android EditText - how to detect if something is written by SoftKey?

Tags: java, android

I want to detect if something put into EditText was put there using SoftKey.

I've overridden `dispatchKeyEvent` but it doesn't work ...

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.e("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769204/detect-input-from-software-or-hardware-keyboard

Comment: @PCGALIANDROID I try do this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
          // like this you can detect 

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
int count) {
       if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
        //your text is not empty
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Ok but it is no answer for my question

Comment: So please explain your question because i probably didn't understand it correctly which means more people didn't understand it.