# How to check whether the input is given by barcode scanner or by soft keyboard?

Tags: android, usb, barcode-scanner, host

I wanted to check **programmatically** that whether the input given by user is either from soft keyboard or the barcode scanner attached to the android tablet.

*There is no edit text in activity where I want to apply this* so please avoid providing solutions that are applicable through EditText.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769204/detect-input-from-software-or-hardware-keyboard

Comment: ok thanks but I wanted to know if in an activity in which there is no edittext but still user giving inputs from hardware keys.

Comment: If there is no `EditText`, then usually there is no input method editor (soft keyboard) showing, and therefore any input is coming from device buttons, Bluetooth keyboards, USB keyboards, etc.

Comment: yes thank you that is one point I can check on and if I have barcode scanner

Answer (score 1):

With dispatchKeyEvent you can listen for any KeyEvent from the barcode scanner.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
// do something on input
   return false; // prevent default behaviour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to read input/values from barcode scanner, so onKeyDown you need to override in your activity/dialog

```
String barcode="";
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    log("Key Down keyCode " + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {//if scanner doesn't return enter key code then make sure that any view must not have focus in window
        //write your code to process the scanned barcode input
        barcode = "";
    } else {
        Character input = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
        log("Scanner Input " + input);
        if (Character.isDigit(input) || Character.isLetter(input)) {
            barcode += input;//concat the characters
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```